# Azure Pipelines YAML: Creating a button

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using YAML pipelines. And we want to add a button in our template file. The problem is that we dont know how to do it. Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by adding a button? Template files are simply scripts, they have no user interface what so ever. Please update the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

on:
push:
branches:
- 'master'
**workflow_dispatch:**